# how can i get extent with click on map with in 25px area of X,Y [openlayers]?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-6

i am getting X,Y on single click.on the map with help of code bellow:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(event) {
  var coordinate = event.coordinate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
   map.on('singleclick', function(event) {
      var x = event.pixel[0];
      var y = event.pixel[1];
      var extent = ol.extent.boundingExtent([ 
        map.getCoordinateFromPixel([x - 25, y - 25]),
        map.getCoordinateFromPixel([x + 25, y - 25]),
        map.getCoordinateFromPixel([x + 25, y + 25]),
        map.getCoordinateFromPixel([x - 25, y + 25])
      ]);
    }
```